# Can't boot into High Sierra (holding option)

Tags: bootcamp, high-sierra

I've been perusing the forums and kind of find some answers for my problem, but kind of not:

Current Hardware:
-Mid 2012 MacBook Pro running High Sierra (fairly certain I went to high sierra)
-240GB Intel SSD
-16GB RAM
-i7 2.3 (quad)
-Bootcamp w/ Windows 10 Home installed

About four weeks ago was the last time I booted into OSX. Restarted, and ever since, it defaulted to Windows - wasn't a big problem as I've had to use that more often as of late.

-Right click Bootcamp control panel, Restart in OSX, and it says OSX can't be found.
-Restart, hold Option, only Windows partition is found
-Attempt PRAM & SMC reset (because why not), nothing
-Attempt single user mode & safe mode, only boots to Windows
-Launch Internet recovery (cmd + r)
-Launched disk utility
-See disk0s2 (fairly certain it was 2) (grayed out, can't do any first aid to it, can't mount it)
-Launch terminal
-Issue "diskutil list"
-Issue "diskutil cs list"
-Issue "diskutil apfs list"

Output in pictures[image]. [image]

I see it's still reporting as HFS and not APFS (though I thought High Sierra converted SSD's to APFS).

Any ideas from the members? You guys are all really smart and I generally find most of my answers here, but this one has my stymied big time.

Thanks for your time!

Update: more photo's from new recovery console (High Sierra - accessed by doing cmd+opt+r):

[image][image] [image] [image]

Comment: Have you tried booting into Recovery Mode using Command + Option + R? This downloads the newest available Internet Recovery version. The version of recovery mode you are booting into is somewhere between 10.7 and 10.9, judging by the wallpaper and full screen icon.

Comment: Added updated photo's and info to original post